# Automatically copy text in a Preference Screen

Tags: android, copy, preferenceactivity

This might have been asked before, but I have searched all over for an answer to this and can't find one.

I have a PreferenceScreen in my Android app with a list of EditTextPreferences that I set the value of programmatically in my code. One of these values should not be editable however, but the user must be able to copy the value (to paste on in a specific field on a website). In its current state the user can change it, but I don't want that to happen.

I have tried looking into using android:inputType="none" but it seems that doesn't work.

I came up with a different idea, but I'm not sure if that will work. Can I make it so that when the user clicks on the field it automatically copies the value (and probably shows a toast saying "value copied" or something) so they can paste it somewhere else? Then I could just make it into a regular preference field or something and not have to worry about the user changing the value!

can anyone give me any tips regarding this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes that is possible.

Make it a `<Preference>`

After that you can add an on click listener like

```
    getPreferenceScreen().findPreference(prefkey)
        .setOnPreferenceClickListener(new OnPreferenceClickListener(){
        public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference)
        {   
            String oldValue = sharedPreferences.getString(prefkey, prefdefaultvalue);

            // You can do what you want here like copy value to clipboard and display toast

        return true;
        }});
```

Comment: Thanks! I combined both your answers and it worked perfectly (after some adaptation to my code of course)!

Answer (score 1):

It simple!
You can custom a layout that same as your PreferenceScreen above.
With each EditText, set android:textIsSelectable="true" to make text selectable first. After editText.setCustomSelectionActionModeCallback(actionModeCallback); to display contextual action mode(a floating menu with buttons you define correspond with your function you want). You can Google this for implementation detail.
Third, Copying and Adding Text to Clipboard

```
private void copyText() {
    ClipboardManager clipboardManager = (ClipboardManager)
            getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);

    CharSequence selectedTxt =  yourEditText.getText().subSequence(yourEditText.getSelectionStart(), yourEditText.getSelectionEnd());
    ClipData clipData = ClipData.newPlainText("text view", selectedTxt);
    clipboardManager.setPrimaryClip(clipData);
}
```

Since now, your copied text is in Clipboard and you can paste it into other supported view.

Comment: Thanks! I combined both your answers and it worked perfectly (after some adaptation to my code of course)!